# LuaLaTeX ignoring newgeometry command

Tags: luatex, geometry

In using the `newgeometry` command in LuaLaTeX, the command does not appear to have effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{luacode, lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
    tex.print("\\newgeometry{margin=3in}")

    tex.print("\\lipsum[4]")
\end{luacode}
\end{document}
```

Output showing margins at 1 inch:
[image: Example output]

Comment: luacode is an enviroment, it builds a group. Use `\directlua{  tex.print("\\newgeometry{margin=3in}")}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I wonder whether the `luacode` package should be patched to not group it.  It seems to be a frequent gotcha among LuaLaTeX users.

Comment: @HenriMenke well it would not a bad idea if the package could provide an ungrouped version. You could write Manuel to suggest this. But \begin opens a group everywhere in latex, so I wouldn't change this.